# Switching to First tab using Selenium Web Driver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

Using selenium web driver with java, i am trying to automate a functionality where i click on a link and it opens a new tab. I want to write a global method for first tab which when called in main test class switches to second tab. I have a separate method to do the assertions on second tab, after the assertions are complete. I want to write another global method which when called closed the second tab and switches back to the first one and resumes the tests on first window.

I have written the below methods and tests:

Main test:

```
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "TestThis", description = "ClickThere", groups = {"hello" })

public void AttributeValidationOnHelpPage(TestData testData, String Id, String TableName) {

        menu.switch(Id);
        data = menu.clickData();
        data.selectNoneDateRange();
        TablePage = data.openTable(TableName);
        TablePage.clickAttTab();
        menuPage.clickOnHelpPage();

        // This method, when called will switch to second tab.
         helpPage = menu.switcToHelpPage();

        // After swicthing below is the assertions i want to do on the second tab.

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("Second page Url."));
        String actualValue = helpOnThisPage.getRefTableAttributes();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualValue, "Reference Table Attributes", "Reference Table Attributes Missing");

        // This method, will close the second tab and switches back to first tab and resumes the test.
        helpPage.switchBackTOMainApplication();

    }


    Global Method for Swicthing to second tab:

    public HelpPage switchToHelpPage() {
        String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(8);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.documentReady());
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.isNotLoading());
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            }
        }
        return new HelpPage(driver);
    }


    Global Method for closing the second tab and swicthing back to first tab.

    public boolean switchBackTOMainApplication() {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            }
        }
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
        return isValid;
    }
```

Here is the problem i am facing. When "helpPage.switchBackTOMainApplication()" method is called its closing the first tab instead of switching to it. Is there any modification i need to do, which will close the second tab and continue the tests on first tab.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "originalHandle" in switchBackTOMainApplication() is having the handle for the second tab as the go back was performed with second tab as current window. The code s
hould be changed as :-

```
public boolean switchBackTOMainApplication() {
    boolean isValid = false;
    String handleToClose = driver.getWindowHandle();
    String mainHandle;
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!handle.equals(handleToClose)) {
            mainHandle=handle;
        }
    }
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(mainHandle);
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: The above method will work only if the driver is on the second opened tab when the method call is made.

Answer (score 0):

When you click to link you should switch to opened tab and do your validation

```
public void switchToNextTab() {
        ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
    }
```

After that, you should return to your main tab

```
public void switchTomainTab() {
    ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(0));
}
```

If you need to close opened tab and then return to the main tab use this

```
public void closeTabAndReturn() {
        driver.close();
        ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(0));
    }
```